# remix ERC223: This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, contract-deployment, erc-223

I can't implement `ERC223` contract.
remix said

> " This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be
>   created."

please tell me what bad it is.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

library SafeMath {
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        uint256 c = a * b;
        assert(c / a == b);
        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a / b;
        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b = a);
        return c;
    }
}

contract Ownable {
    address public owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    function Ownable() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
        require(newOwner != address(0));
        OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

contract ERC223 {
    uint public totalSupply;

    function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint);
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256 _supply);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns (bool ok);
    function transfer(address to, uint value, bytes data) public returns (bool ok);
    function transfer(address to, uint value, bytes data, string customFallback) public returns (bool ok);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value, bytes indexed data);

    function name() public view returns (string _name);
    function symbol() public view returns (string _symbol);
    function decimals() public view returns (uint8 _decimals);

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining);
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint _value);
}



 contract ContractReceiver {

    struct TKN {
        address sender;
        uint value;
        bytes data;
        bytes4 sig;
    }

    function tokenFallback(address _from, uint _value, bytes _data) public pure {
        TKN memory tkn;
        tkn.sender = _from;
        tkn.value = _value;
        tkn.data = _data;
        uint32 u = uint32(_data[3]) + (uint32(_data[2])  uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;
    mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;
    mapping (address => uint256) public unlockUnixTime;

    event FrozenFunds(address indexed target, bool frozen);
    event LockedFunds(address indexed target, uint256 locked);
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 amount);
    event Mint(address indexed to, uint256 amount);
    event MintFinished();

    function New() public {
        owner = founder;
        balanceOf[founder] = totalSupply.mul(40).div(100);
        balanceOf[AirDrop] = totalSupply.mul(50).div(100);
        balanceOf[sale] = totalSupply.mul(10).div(100);
    }

    function name() public view returns (string _name) {
        return name;
    }

    function symbol() public view returns (string _symbol) {
        return symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public view returns (uint8 _decimals) {
        return decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256 _totalSupply) {
        return totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balanceOf[_owner];
    }

    function freezeAccounts(address[] targets, bool isFrozen) onlyOwner public {
        require(targets.length > 0);

        for (uint j = 0; j  0
                && targets.length == unixTimes.length);

        for(uint j = 0; j  0
                && frozenAccount[msg.sender] == false
                && frozenAccount[_to] == false
                && now > unlockUnixTime[msg.sender]
                && now > unlockUnixTime[_to]);

        if (isContract(_to)) {
            require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = balanceOf[msg.sender].sub(_value);
            balanceOf[_to] = balanceOf[_to].add(_value);
            assert(_to.call.value(0)(bytes4(keccak256(_custom_fallback)), msg.sender, _value, _data));
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, _data);
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else {
            return transferToAddress(_to, _value, _data);
        }
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) public  returns (bool success) {
        require(_value > 0
                && frozenAccount[msg.sender] == false
                && frozenAccount[_to] == false
                && now > unlockUnixTime[msg.sender]
                && now > unlockUnixTime[_to]);

        if (isContract(_to)) {
            return transferToContract(_to, _value, _data);
        } else {
            return transferToAddress(_to, _value, _data);
        }
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value > 0
                && frozenAccount[msg.sender] == false
                && frozenAccount[_to] == false
                && now > unlockUnixTime[msg.sender]
                && now > unlockUnixTime[_to]);

        bytes memory empty;
        if (isContract(_to)) {
            return transferToContract(_to, _value, empty);
        } else {
            return transferToAddress(_to, _value, empty);
        }
    }


    function isContract(address _addr) private view returns (bool is_contract) {
        uint length;
        assembly {
            length := extcodesize(_addr)
        }
        return (length > 0);
    }

    function transferToAddress(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) private returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = balanceOf[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balanceOf[_to] = balanceOf[_to].add(_value);
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, _data);
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferToContract(address _to, uint _value, bytes _data) private returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = balanceOf[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balanceOf[_to] = balanceOf[_to].add(_value);
        ContractReceiver receiver = ContractReceiver(_to);
        receiver.tokenFallback(msg.sender, _value, _data);
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, _data);
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_to != address(0)
                && _value > 0
                && balanceOf[_from] >= _value
                && allowance[_from][msg.sender] >= _value
                && frozenAccount[_from] == false
                && frozenAccount[_to] == false
                && now > unlockUnixTime[_from]
                && now > unlockUnixTime[_to]);

        balanceOf[_from] = balanceOf[_from].sub(_value);
        balanceOf[_to] = balanceOf[_to].add(_value);
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] = allowance[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
        return allowance[_owner][_spender];
    }
    function burn(address _from, uint256 _unitAmount) onlyOwner public {
        require(_unitAmount > 0
                && balanceOf[_from] >= _unitAmount);

        balanceOf[_from] = balanceOf[_from].sub(_unitAmount);
        totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(_unitAmount);
        Burn(_from, _unitAmount);
    }


    modifier canMint() {
        require(!mintingFinished);
        _;
    }
    function mint(address _to, uint256 _unitAmount) onlyOwner canMint public returns (bool) {
        require(_unitAmount > 0);

        totalSupply = totalSupply.add(_unitAmount);
        balanceOf[_to] = balanceOf[_to].add(_unitAmount);
        Mint(_to, _unitAmount);
        Transfer(address(0), _to, _unitAmount);
        return true;
    }
    function finishMinting() onlyOwner canMint public returns (bool) {
        mintingFinished = true;
        MintFinished();
        return true;
    }
    function distributeAirdrop(address[] addresses, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
        require(amount > 0
                && addresses.length > 0
                && frozenAccount[msg.sender] == false
                && now > unlockUnixTime[msg.sender]);

        amount = amount.mul(1e8);
        uint256 totalAmount = amount.mul(addresses.length);
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= totalAmount);

        for (uint j = 0; j  unlockUnixTime[addresses[j]]);

            balanceOf[addresses[j]] = balanceOf[addresses[j]].add(amount);
            Transfer(msg.sender, addresses[j], amount);
        }
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = balanceOf[msg.sender].sub(totalAmount);
        return true;
    }

    function distributeAirdrop(address[] addresses, uint[] amounts) public returns (bool) {
        require(addresses.length > 0
                && addresses.length == amounts.length
                && frozenAccount[msg.sender] == false
                && now > unlockUnixTime[msg.sender]);

        uint256 totalAmount = 0;

        for(uint j = 0; j  0
                    && addresses[j] != 0x0
                    && frozenAccount[addresses[j]] == false
                    && now > unlockUnixTime[addresses[j]]);

            amounts[j] = amounts[j].mul(1e8);
            totalAmount = totalAmount.add(amounts[j]);
        }
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= totalAmount);

        for (j = 0; j  0
                && addresses.length == amounts.length);

        uint256 totalAmount = 0;

        for (uint j = 0; j  0
                    && addresses[j] != 0x0
                    && frozenAccount[addresses[j]] == false
                    && now > unlockUnixTime[addresses[j]]);

            amounts[j] = amounts[j].mul(1e8);
            require(balanceOf[addresses[j]] >= amounts[j]);
            balanceOf[addresses[j]] = balanceOf[addresses[j]].sub(amounts[j]);
            totalAmount = totalAmount.add(amounts[j]);
            Transfer(addresses[j], msg.sender, amounts[j]);
        }
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = balanceOf[msg.sender].add(totalAmount);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
contract ContractReceiver
```

To this:

```
contract ContractReceiver is ERC223
```

And then deploy `ContractReceiver` instead of `ERC223`.

In addition, you're better off also changing this:

```
contract ERC223
```

To this:

```
interface ERC223
```

And then moving `uint public totalSupply` from `ERC223` to `ContractReceiver`.

In fact, it is possible that you have to do it; I doubt that `contract ERC223` will compile otherwise.

Comment: thank you for replying.
But, I have not been able to run as ever.

Comment: @yoru: Remix points you to the compilation errors. You should by the least know how to read and resolve them. If you have a problem with this kind of errors, then it will be a lot worse when you start dealing with runtime errors (which no one will point you to, in opposed to compilation errors). If you're still having problems with a specific compilation error emitted by Remix, then you should by the least post it here and ask for a specific direction. What you did here instead is "dump my code and expect someone else to solve everything for me", which does not encourage anyone to help you!

Comment: Thank you for helping.
I don't find compile error.
but,I can't deploy ERC223.
But,I can deploy other contract.

Comment: @yoru: Did you read what I wrote? You cannot deploy contract `ERC223`, because it doesn't implement the functions declared in it! You should either implement them in this contract, or implement them in the inheriting contract and deploy that contract instead.

Comment: I'm sorry.
I am not good at English.
I read  thoroughly.

Comment: @yoru: Do you understand WHY you cannot deploy this contract?

Comment: `In fact, it is possible that you have to do it; I doubt that contract ERC223 will compile otherwise.`@goodvibration I always use contracts instead of interfaces, for the precise reason that you can embed variables in them, which is especially useful for constants. It will compile fine as a contract.